# Need a word list from the internet

Tags: java, arrays, applet

Hello I'm creating a HangMan game and I want the array list of words to come from the internet.  Its not initializing for me.  Can anyone help?  This is the code.

```
public String getaword()
{

     try
     {
        URL url = new URL ("http://dictionary-thesaurus.com/wordlists/Adjectives%28929%29.txt");
        //URLConnection urlConnection = (URLConnection)url.openConnection();
        //inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str=null;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            while((str = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.add(str);
                words = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
            }
     }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
   Random r = new Random();
   int num;
   num = r.nextInt(words.length);  
   return words[num];
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `Its not initializing for me` is not very helpful in describing your problem.  What is the error and what line of code?

Comment: Sorry this method is invoked when the applet is initializing and it is not returning a word.  I know at some point I need to trim it down to a specific part of the HTML code but right now its not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        URL url = new URL ("http://dictionary-thesaurus.com/wordlists/Adjectives(929).txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str = null;
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(str);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(lines);
}
```